# How can I make a heatmap with uneven y-axis?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, heatmap

How can I make a heatmap (or if it is called something else) when the y-axis is uneven? I am open to interpolation too, but preferably without it.

When I had the layer in even intervals, I could plot using this to get the figure below

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=time, y=Layer, fill = Value))+
  geom_tile()+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue",mid="yellow",high="red", midpoint=0.5)+
  theme_bw()
```

But I am unable to proceed when layer is not from 1-10 natural numbers.

[image]

```
dput(droplevels(head(smx,10)))

structure(list(value = c(5.4023420028113e-07, 5.4023420028113e-07, 
    5.4023420028113e-07, 5.4023420028113e-07, 5.4023420028113e-07, 
    5.4023420028113e-07, 5.4023420028113e-07, 6.74006442227979e-08, 
    6.74006442227979e-08, 6.74006442227979e-08), 
time = structure(c(17156, 17156, 17156, 17156, 17156, 17156, 17156, 17162,     
    17162, 17162), 
class = "Date"), 
layer = c(0.0120349472577243, 0.0177233992991887, 0.00844582491793334,   
    0.00756873916071316, 0.0437965816456147, 0.0168056962032031, 
    0.0181395468747096, 0.0120349472577243, 0.0177233992991887, 
    0.00844582491793334)), 
.Names = c("value", "time", "layer"), 
row.names = c(NA, 10L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

**FULL DATA IS HERE**

https://pastebin.com/mXUiSyvX

Comment: What specifically goes wrong when you try to plot your data, and how do you want the final plot to look?

Comment: Basically, I got horizontal lines and no blocks. The final plot should like the one I attached, But basically, uneven sized blocks everywhere...

Comment: So the tiles should cover the whole plot area, or cover up to the bottom of the next tile? You need to think about how the time and layer values in your data map to the tiles you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `geom_rect` instead of `geom_tile` to specify varying tile height. From the help file:

> geom_rect and geom_tile do the same thing, but are parameterised
>   differently: geom_rect uses the locations of the four corners (**xmin,**
>   **xmax, ymin and ymax**), while geom_tile uses the center of the tile and
>   its size (x, y, width, height).

Assuming that the layer variable in your data frame refers to the top of each tile (i.e. ymax), you can create a lagged layer variable for each date so that you get the ymin in the same row of the data frame. Based on your dataset, I also assumed the lowest tile starts at ymin = 0:

```
library(dplyr)

ggplot(smx %>%
         group_by(time) %>%
         arrange(layer) %>%
         mutate(layer.min = layer - diff(c(0, layer))) %>% #assuming y axis starts from 0
         ungroup(), aes(fill = value))+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = time - 0.5, xmax = time + 0.5,
                ymin = layer.min, ymax = layer),
            colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue",mid="yellow",high="red", midpoint = 0.2) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels = "%b %d") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: ggplot heatmap using geom_rect]

(I included black outline for the tiles & changed the midpoint for clearer visual distinction in this answer. Do feel free to remove them for your actual use case.)